# access to nested objects and arrays React

Tags: reactjs

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    questionText: "",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
    ],
  });
```

How can I change the value of answerText or isCorrect in onChange of input tag?

```
<input
        type="text"
       
        onChange={(event) =>
          setData({ ...data, answerText: event.target.value })
        }
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `answerOptions` is an array so you need to follow the same spread operator for the array also.

```js
data = {
    questionText: "",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "" },
    ],
  }
  
console.log({...data, answerOptions: [...data.answerOptions, {answerText: 'something', isCorrect: "some value"}]})
```

The above code will add a new object to an existing array. If you want to edit the existing object, I would suggest using a unique identifier to find out the object and update it using `.map()`

```js
data = {
    questionText: "",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "", id: 1 },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "", id: 2 },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "", id: 3 },
      { answerText: "", isCorrect: "", id: 4 },
    ],
  }
  
console.log({...data,
    answerOptions: [...data.answerOptions.map(element => element.id == 2 ? { ...element, answerText: 'updated text' } : element)]
})
```

You can try the same logic in you react app and update your state variable